# Cantor's theorem with Nested Intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I am looking for an explained proof of the uncountability of R using Nested Intervals, i.e. Cantor's first proof. I have not seen it in the answered questions of the site so I thought I should ask.

From what I can tell, the validity of the proof is still disputed but nevertheless it is good to know! Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a reference for which proof you are referring to here? The only proof I recall is Cantor's Diagonalization Proof, but I wouldn't say that its validity has been called into question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,\dots$ is an enumeration of $I_0=[0,1]$. Take the interval $[0,1]$ and consider the two thirds intervals: $[0,1/3]$, $[2/3,1]$. Let $I_1$ be one of these intervals which does not contain $x_1$. Then proceed by dividing $I_1$ in three parts and considering two of them which are disjoint. Let $I_2$ be the one not containing $x_2$.

Going on like that you find a sequence of intervals: $I_1 \supset I_2 \supset \dots \supset I_n \supset\dots$. By the continuity axiom there is a point $\bar x$ in the intersection of all these intervals. By construction this point is different from any $x_n$ since $\bar x \in I_n$ while $x_n \not \in I_n$.

Comment: But if the intersections are infinite then by construction there is no point that is included in each one of the intervals.

Comment: No point of the sequence is included in each interval. But the intersection theorem states that the intersection is not empty... hence you get a contradiction.

Comment: @Clayton It is because we have assumed that $$x_n \notin I_n $$ and if the intersection includes all real numbers then clearly $$ \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}= \emptyset $$

Comment: @Ioannis: Ah, I see; I misinterpreted your question. My apologies.

Comment: @Clayton Well, what I do not understand is why this show that R is uncountable. This not mathematicals but paraphysics if you ask me. Total nuts.

Comment: @Ioannis what is not clear to you? The proof shows that given any sequence of real numbers in [0,1] there is a number in [0,1] which is not in the sequence. As a consequence [0,1] is not countable.

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Thanks for your response first of all. Then it is the applicattion of the continuity axiom that I do not understand. We have deliberately constructed a sequence like that. The intersection is of course empty and I do not understand how the continuity axiom saves the day. I guess my point is that no matter how we define the sets if $$I_n \subset I_{n+1}\ \text{and}\ x_n \notin I_n $$ this follows for all such sequences. That's all.

Comment: @Ioannis: It is a standard theorem that if $\langle I_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a sequence of closed intervals in $\Bbb R$ such that $I_{n+1}\subseteq I_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, then $\bigcup_{n\ge 1}I_n\ne\varnothing$. You can find a proof in any decent real analysis text. It follows from the fact that every non-empty subset of $\Bbb R$ that is bounded above has a least upper bound. As Emanuele showed you, if $C\subseteq\Bbb R$ is countable, one can construct such a nest of closed intervals whose intersection is disjoint from $C$. Since the intersection is known not to be empty, ...

Comment: ... $C$ cannot be all of $\Bbb R$. And since $C$ is an arbitrary countable subset of $\Bbb R$, this means that $\Bbb R$ itself cannot be countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you Brian.

Comment: @Ioannis: You’re welcome.