# Problem while proving: "The set of rational numbers does not satisfy Cantor's nested interval property ".

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Justify whether the set of rational numbers satisfy
Cantor's nested interval property ?

This might be a popular question. I sought to disaprove this fact as follows:

Say for contradiction we assume that the Nested Interval Property  is valid in $\Bbb Q.$ Also, we know that there exists an increasing sequence , $p_n$ which converges to $\sqrt 2$ (for eg: $1,1.4,1.414,1.4142,...$ is a sequence which is increasing and converges to $\sqrt 2$ ) and there exists a sequence $q_n$ converging to $\sqrt 2$ and is decreasing. Now, we construct intervals, as $I_1=[p_1,q_1], I_2=[p_2,q_2],I_3=[p_3,q_3]$ and so on, such that each $I_n\subset \Bbb Q.$

We note that $....\subset I_4\subset I_3\subset I_2\subset I_1$ is a nested sequence of closed intervals, with $\bigcap I_n=\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q$ and so, $\bigcap I_n$ is empty in $\Bbb Q.$ And since we are working in $\Bbb Q$, so, $\bigcap I_n=\emptyset,$ a contradiction. This, proves,Cantor's Nested Interval Property  doesn't necessarily hold in $\Bbb Q.$

---

However,   I  feel that I have a problem in my proof , for I was unable to prove that the sequence of closed nested intervals $I_n=[p_n,q_n]$  has the length of the intervals $|I_n|=q_n-p_n$ converging to zero. In other words, I need to show, $\lim |I_n|=0$ to conclude that $\sqrt 2$ is the one and only one element in their intersection. Any help regarding how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info What are your "specific concerns or doubts about the validity of that solution"? " why the argument presented is not convincing enough"?

Comment: You should clarify whether your $I_n$ are intervals in $\Bbb Q$ or in $\Bbb R.$ It seems to vary: "$\bigcap I_n=\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q$ and so, $\bigcap I_n$ is empty in $\Bbb Q.$ ". Better stay always with intervals in $\Bbb Q,$ to stick to the question. (Incidentally, in $\Bbb R,$ the correct formulation would be "$\bigcap I_n=\{\sqrt 2\}\not\subset\Bbb Q$".)

Comment: You forgot to delete " with $\bigcap I_n=\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q$ and so, $\bigcap I_n$ is empty in $\Bbb Q.$ And since we are working in $\Bbb Q$, so, ".

Comment: They are indeed now clearly defined as subsets of $\Bbb Q,$ so you must remove the contradictory portion of sentence incriminated in my previous comment. As for your new question about constructivity, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/981626/386889) should please you.

Comment: The simplest way to get a decreasing sequence to $\sqrt 2$ would be to do exactly the same thing you did for the increasing sequence, except round up each time instead of rounding down.

Comment: @ThomasFinley I suspect you're overthinking this: $$2, 1.5, 1.42, 1.415, 1.4143 ...$$ do you see the pattern?

Comment: As Noah Schweber says, $q_n$ is always identical to $p_n$, except for adding $1$ to the least significant digit. $$p_n = 10^{-n}\lfloor 10^n\sqrt 2\rfloor\\q_n = 10^{-n}\lceil 10^n\sqrt 2\rceil = p_n + 10^{-n}$$where the last equation always holds since $10^n\sqrt 2$ is never integer.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah, Thanks a ton!

Comment: @PaulSinclair I  was really impressed with Noah Schweber's example, but the thing is, we have still one more unfinished buisness here, and that is, to prove that the length of the intervals $[p_n,q_n]$ converges to $0.$ How do we prove it? Thanks!

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think there's one more thing left to establish, i.e the length of the intervals $[p_n,q_n]$ in the OP converges to $0$, else we cannot assert that their intersection will contain one and only one point. Can you help me with that?

Comment: $q_n - p_n = 10^{-n}$, as I pointed out in my previous comment. I don't see how proving that $10^{-n} \to 0$ is hard to do.

Comment: @PaulSinclair But the point is, I don't understand how did you write $p_n=10^{-n}\lfloor 10^n\sqrt 2\rfloor$ ? Would you mind explaining that ? Thank you!

Comment: @AnneBauval I have edited my question. If it still interests you,  then you might want to take a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer $\le x$. Likewise $\lceil x \rceil$ denotes the least integer $\ge x$. When $x$ is integer, the two are equal. If $x$ is not integer, then $\lceil x \rceil = \lfloor x \rfloor + 1$. To truncate $x$ to $n$ digits to the right of the decimal point, you first multiply $x$ by $10^n$, which moves the $n$ digits to the left of the decimal point. Then take $\lfloor 10^nx\rfloor$ to remove all the decimals still to the right of the decimal point. Then multiply by $10^{-n}$ to move those $n$ decimals back to the right of the decimal point again.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Oh! Thanks a lot! I do understand it clearly. If you consider adding your comment as an answer, I 'll be glad accepting it.

Comment: Again: you forgot to delete "with $\bigcap I_n=\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q$ and so, $\bigcap I_n$ is empty in $\Bbb Q.$ And since we are working in $\Bbb Q$, so,". As for your remaining question, no need of an explicit formula for $p_n$ and $q_n$. It is more readable to write: "let $p_n<q_n$ be the two decimal numbers approximating $\sqrt2$ from below and from above up to $10^{-n}$".

Comment: Again: you forgot to delete "with $\bigcap I_n=\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q$ and so, $\bigcap I_n$ is empty in $\Bbb Q.$ And since we are working in $\Bbb Q$, so,". As for your remaining question, no need of an explicit formula for $p_n$ and $q_n$. It is more readable to write: "let $p_n<q_n$ be the two decimal numbers approximating $\sqrt2$ from below and from above up to $10^{-n}$".

Comment: You may try the repeated bisection approach without specifically looking for the sequence made using decimal approximations to $\sqrt{2}$. Start with rational interval $I_1=[1,2]$ and bisect it into two equal intervals via midpoint $1.5$. One of these intervals will be such that square of left end point is less than $2$ and square of right end point will be greater than $2$. Call that $I_2$ (here $I_2=[1,1.5]$). Repeat the procedure to get the desired sequence of nested intervals $I_n$ whose length tends to $0$.